# i want to generate on click event as well as open a dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-click-event

My dialoge box works fine on clicking a button. but control not going to click event in .cs page

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its impossible to give solution, Nonetheless you can try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id/class-ofcontrol', function(){
  //-----code stuff here---------//
});
```